# How to detect a required field from a fieldset?

Tags: fieldsets

I have this fieldset on my page which uses SLDS design:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="ppCard">
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.my_Object__c.FieldSets.myFieldset}" var="ap1">
    <apex:inputField value="{!ps[ap1.fieldPath]}" 
         styleClass="{! IF((ap1.fieldPath == 'field1'), 'fieldValue1', '')} 
                     {! IF((ap1.fieldPath == 'field2'), 'fieldValue2', '')} inputfield"
         label="{! IF((ap1.fieldPath == 'field1'), ap1.label+' (without Salutation)', ap1.label)}" 
         required="{!OR(ap1.required, ap1.dbrequired)}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

If a field is required on fieldset definition, I would like its inputfield to be red also on page load. How can I get the specific field to be able to change its required attribute? For now, I am just making all inputfields required on page but not on the field set definition. I want to make it required only if it is also required on fieldset. Is there any way on how to do it?

For example: if field2 is the only field required on fieldset, I want to remove also the required attribute of field1 on page. Like using `$('.samplestyleclass').val('').removeAttr('required')` on JS for example... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think following logic might work for you. Display fields based on `rendered` condition as follows:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.my_Object__c.FieldSets.myFieldset}" var="ap1">

    <!-- This is non mandatory block -->
    <apex:inputField value="{!ps[ap1.fieldPath]}" 
             label="{! IF((ap1.fieldPath == 'field1'), ap1.label+' (without Salutation)', ap1.label)}" 
             rendered="{!NOT(AND(ap1.required, ap1.dbrequired))}"/>

     <!-- This is mandatory block -->
     <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput" rendered="{!OR(ap1.required, ap1.dbrequired)}">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredBlock"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!ps[ap1.fieldPath]}" 
         label="{! IF((ap1.fieldPath == 'field1'), ap1.label+' (without Salutation)', ap1.label)}" 
         required="true" />
     </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```